# Get value from map using a String bean as a key in SPEL

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I would like to know how to get value from the spring defined Map using a String bean as a key.

I have the following map defined in my xml:

```
<bean id="myMap" class="java.util.HashMap">
    <constructor-arg>
        <util:map>
            <entry key="key1" value="Value1"/>
            <entry key="key2" value="Value2"/>
        </util:map>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

And I have the following simple String bean:

```
<bean id="mySimpleString" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg value="key1"/>
</bean>
```

To get the value I'm using SPEL in my xml as follows:

```
<bean class="com.my.MyClass">
    <property name="someProp" value="#{myMap[#mySimpleString]}"/>
</bean>
```

And I get null in my `someProp` value.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I no expert but I would say the second "#" needs to be removed

Comment: I've already tried it but it didn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as `myMap` is a `Map` you should use `#get()` method to retrieve the value.
this would work

```
<property name="someProp" value="#{myMap.get(mySimpleString)}"/>
```

Comment: Cool, it works! Thanks! But why the expression with brackets works if I use a string value like that: `#{myMap['key1']}`?

Comment: I'm not sure about the reason why it works, as normally it should not and BeanExpressionException should be raised. but anyway it should relate to SPEL processing.